# Saving an SvgJS generated drawing as a .PNG or .GIF

Tags: javascript, svg, png, svg.js

I have used the SVG.js library to generate SVG drawings on a webpage. Using FileSaver.js, I can save them as `.SVG` files. I would like to also give users the option of saving `.PNG` files.

I have tried some of the solutions that use the canvas, but no luck yet.

Comment: It really boils down to a goodle search. You need a libraray or program which can convert svgs to pngs for you.

Comment: Thanks, That is what I have been doing. I think my issue is that I am using the SVG.js library to generate the SVG. There seems to be a lot of solutions to convert regularly generated SVGs, but they don't work for me.